# Cutout in one side of the div border and display parent body color in it

Tags: html, css

Here is the complete scenario.
we have a container that had background image, then we have a card on top of that which has a cutout on lower right hand side of it. Through this cutout we want to show the container's or body's bg color. if we move the card with transition that bg should change. I have attached the required image below and highlighted the section that we want to do.

[image]

Comment: I suspect you'll need some sort of [clip path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) on the card.

Answer (score 0):

same not but can try this code :

```css
html,body{
  box-sizing:border-box;
  margin:0;
  padding:10px;
  height:100%;
  background:#fadaa7;
}
.wrap{
  width:600px;
}
.coupon{
  display:inline-block;
  overflow:hidden;
  border-radius:10px;
}
.coupon-left{
  float:left;
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  position:relative;
}
.coupon-left::before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right:0;
  height:50%;
  background:radial-gradient(circle at right top, transparent 10px, #252525 10px, #252525 10px)
}
.coupon-left::after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right:0;
  height:50%;
  background:radial-gradient(circle at right bottom, transparent 10px, #252525 10px, #252525 10px)
}
.coupon-con{
  float:left;
  width:350px;
  height:150px;
  position:relative;
}
.coupon-con::before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right:0;
  height:50%;
  background:radial-gradient(circle at left top, transparent 10px, #252525 10px, #fff 10px)
}
.coupon-con::after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right:0;
  height:50%;
  background:radial-gradient(circle at left bottom, transparent 10px, #252525 10px, #fff 10px)
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="coupon">
    <div class="coupon-left"></div>
    <div class="coupon-con"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `clip-path` in your css as this:

```css
body {
    background-color: blue;
}

.coupon {
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
    background-color: white;
    width: 660px;
    height: 380px;
    clip-path: path("M 30 0 L 630 0 A 30 30 0 0 1 660 30 L 660 240 A 30 30 0 0 0 660 300 L 660 350 A 30 30 0 0 1 630 380 L 30 380 A 30 30 0 0 1 0 350 L 0 300 A 30 30 0 0 0 0 240 L 0 30 A 30 30 0 0 1 30 0");
}

.left {
    width: 33%;
    background-color: black;
}

.right {
    width: 66%;
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="coupon">
 <div class="left">
    
 </div>
 <div class="right">
    
 </div>
</div>
```

Check https://caniuse.com/?search=clip-path for browser support.